# Getting "no such table" error even though table exists

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

From an existing SQLite database I am trying to read data using SQLAlchemy:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///history.db"

db = SQLAlchemy()
db.init_app(app)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"


class history(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    datetime = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    system = db.Column(db.String)
    error = db.Column(db.Integer)
    details = db.Column(db.String)


@app.route("/point1")
def point1():
    systems = db.session.execute(db.select(history).order_by(history.system)).scalars()
    return systems

@app.route("/point2")
def point2():
    return list(db.metadata.tables.keys())
```

Calling `point2` returns `["history"]`. But calling `point1` generates the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: history
[SQL: SELECT history.id, history.datetime, history.system, history.error, history.details
FROM history ORDER BY history.system]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)
```

What am I missing?

- The SQLite database is in the same folder as the Python script.
- The database was generated using a separate Python script that used SQLAlchemy (not Flask_SQLAlchemy).
- This script is running on Python 3.10.6 using a virtual environment.
- This is running on Windows 10.

Comment: If you browse the database using a separate app, is the table present?

Comment: Yes, the table is present using an external application (SQLiteDatabaseBrowser) and even via a different python script (using sqlite3)